# Is there a way to handle "nested iFrames" in protractor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor to test non-angular application and in a scenario i had nested "iFrames", these iFrames are in div tag. Using protractor i was able to navigate to second iFrame, but could not read any elements on page. Let me know if you have any suggestions on this.

```
<div class="modal-content" modal-transclude=""> 
<iframe id="frame1" name="newContentItemframe" onload="onLoadDone();" 
<iframe name="frame2" id="form_iframe" 
<input type="text" class="iw-formspub-textbox-active" name="Content/Title" id="field_0">
</iframe>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you miss adding some data or the `iframe` elements don't have a closing tag? :) Also do you get any error when you try to access the element inside second iframe? Thanks

Comment: Thx for your time Girish. I got it solve, Element was in one more iFrame. Did you work with Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`switchTo()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.TargetLocator.prototype.frame), which takes a *name or index*, to switch to the frame/window containing your elements. Also, don't forget to *switch back!*

```
browser.switchTo().frame('frame2');
// access elements in the frame...

// then switch back to main window
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thax for your time Brine. I got it solve, Element was in one more iFrame. 
Did you work with Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very elegant solution, but picking up the second iframe wasn't working for me, so I had to go with: 
`browser.switchTo().frame(0);`
and then, once in the first frame, again:`browser.switchTo().frame(0);`.